# how to fetch multiple image which are saved in one cell of database table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
**i took multiple image input in this way**

<div class="form-group" style="width: 100%">
  <label for="inputEmail4">Images</label>
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="Image" name="Image[]" multiple="multiple" placeholder="">
</div>
```

i have already inserted images on database. In database each cell containing more than one image path
 [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7U0l.png).
Now i want to fetch and display each image using laravel framework. please suggest what will be the controller code..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour and check How to Ask on how to ask good questions on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your problem, which can be compiled and tested by others which shows how you try to stop making changes to filled cells.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are saving the data in one field separated by colon then you can do(considering your column name is `images`) :

```
$model = ModelName::first();
$images = explode(';', $model->images); //  This fives image1;image2;image3 etc
$images = array_filter(array_map('trim', $images));
// This will give you array ['image1','image2','image3'}
```

However, this is not a good approach as every-time you need to explode it if you want to get a usable data.

Instead, you can specify this column in `protected $casts = ['images' => 'array']`

Then when you do `$model->images`, it w ill directly give you an array of image paths instead of a single string separated by a delimiter. See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) for more help.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Mihir Bhende. But i do not questioned that. i have already inserted images on database. In database multiple image paths are saved  in one cell. Now i actually want to know that how can i fetch each image from database.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would change your data structure, so it easier to store and fetch your images from your database.

You could use a json column and use Mutators to cast the images to a normal php array https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting.

This way you can just loop through the array and display each image.